# Beats in Double slit experiment

Tags: interference, double-slit-experiment

In standard YDSE, if one were to make a small modification, and use 2 light beams with frequencies which are very close to each other, then is it possible to obtain a beats (similar to what in sound) like pattern on the screen. What would the pattern look like, and what would be the function of the intensity.
Also, would it matter if one were to pass one light beam via each slit rather than both the light beams through each slit